# M.2 SSD replacement does not appear on system as expected

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, nvme

I have a [Dell Latitude 3190 2-in-1](https://www.delltechnologies.com/resources/en-us/asset/technical-guides-support-information/products/laptops/Dell_Latitude_3190_2-in-1_Technical_Guidebook.pdf) and I purchased a [256GB VisionTek PRO XPN M.2 NVMe](https://www.visiontek.com/256gb-visiontek-pro-xpn-m-2-nvme-3.html)  SSD drive.

I opened the laptop and removed the old SSD and put the new one in. However I do not see the drive in the BIOS.

What is happening and how can I get the system to recognize th new SSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The
[Latitude 3190 Owner's Manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/latitude-11-3190-laptop/latitude_3190_owners_manual/working-on-your-computer?guid=guid-241fc3c9-f8d6-4284-b8b6-b8e1dfb40745)
says this:

[image]

An M.2 SATA disk is not compatible with M.2 NVMe, although the connectors look the
same. You need to replace the disk with an M.2 SATA disk.

Comment: Oh, weird the technical guide (linked in my post) on page 5 led me to believe the M.2 NVMe would work.  I guess i'll be returning the drives ,I bought 10 , sigh, thanks for  your help